# Elasticsearch: scroll between specified time frame

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I have some data in elasticsearch. as shown in the image

[image]

I used below link example to do the scrolling

https://gist.github.com/drorata/146ce50807d16fd4a6aa

```
page = es.search(
    index = INDEX_NAME,
    scroll = '1m',
    size = 1000,
    body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
    sid = page['_scroll_id']
    scroll_size = page['hits']['total']

    # Start scrolling

    print( "Scrolling...")
    while (scroll_size > 0):


        print("Page: ",count)
        page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '10m')
        # Update the scroll ID
        sid = page['_scroll_id']

        for hit in page['hits']['hits']:
            #some code processing here
```

Currently my requirement is that i want to scroll but want to specify the start timestamp and end timestamp
Need help as to how to do this using scroll.

Comment: in your query itself, you can filter the record by timestamp and afterward you can scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example code. time range should be in es query. Also You should process the first query result.

```
es_query_dict = {"query": {"range": {"timestamp":{
    "gte":"2018-08-00T00:00:00Z", "lte":"2018-08-17T00:00:00Z"}}}}


def get_es_logs():
    es_client = Elasticsearch([source_es_ip], port=9200, timeout=300)

    total_docs = 0
    page = es_client.search(scroll=scroll_time,
                            size=scroll_size,
                            body=json.dumps(es_query_dict))
    while True:
        sid = page['_scroll_id']
        details = page["hits"]["hits"]
        doc_count = len(details)
        if len(details) > 0:
            total_docs += doc_count
            print("scroll size: " + str(doc_count))
            print("start bulk index docs")
            # index_bulk(details)
            print("end success")
        else:
            break
        page = es_client.scroll(scroll_id=sid, scroll=scroll_time)

    print("total docs: " + str(total_docs))
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply replace

```
body={"query": {"match_all": {}}})
```

by

```
body={"query": {"range": {"timestamp":{"gte":"2018-08-05T05:30:00Z", "glte":"2018-08-06T05:30:00Z"}}}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at `elasticsearch.helpers.scan` where you already have the loop logic implemented for you, just pass it `query={"query": {"range": {"timestamp": {"gt": ..., "lt": ...}}}}`